# How to deal with dicts in pydantic

Tags: python, python-3.x, pymongo, fastapi, pydantic

I have a model like this:

```
class User(BaseModel):
    email: str
    emailVerified: Any
```

Example:

```
{
    "email": "laclance@gmail.com",
    "emailVerified": {
        "$date": "2022-03-09T19:45:23.613Z"
    }
}
```

and a route to get all users:

```
@users.get('/', response_model=list[User])
async def find_all_users():
    return list(conn.mydb.users.find())
```

`emailVerified: Any` in the model works and returns `"emailVerified": "2022-03-09T19:45:23.613Z"`

`emailVerified: dict[str,str]` results in error `str type expected`

`emailVerified: str` results in error `value is not a valid dict`

I don't mind if i get just a string instead of a dict but surely I'm doing something wrong if I have to use Any?

Comment: Hey Lance, can you please provide some details about your model and code in order to understand the problem better?

Comment: not sure what you mean by details but ill add my model, dont see how it will help though

Answer (score 1):

As per the [documentation](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/body-nested-models/#declare-a-list-with-a-type-parameter):

> To declare types that have type parameters (internal types), like
> `list`, `dict`, `tuple`:
>
> If you are in a Python version **lower than 3.9**, import their equivalent
> version from the `typing` module.

Thus, your Python version is most likely lower than 3.9, if you get an error when defining `dict[str, str]`. You could check your Python version by running `python --version` in a terminal, or in your script run `import sys` to get the module and use `sys.version` to get the version information.

Therefore, as described above, you should use the [`typing`](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/types/#typing-iterables) library to import the `Dict` type, and use as follows (see the example given [here](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/body-nested-models/#bodies-of-arbitrary-dicts) as well):

```
from typing import Dict

class User(BaseModel):
    email: str
    emailVerified: Dict[str,str]
```

Comment: Thanks but I know that, I am using 3.10

Comment: I dont get the error when defining, only when going to /users route

Comment: All the code to reproduce is in the question besides import statements and mongodb connection which is a one line, very simple  app just 7 lines of code without import statements so didn't see the need for an example repo

Comment: Clearly mongodb saves datetimes that look like a python dict, `{"$date": "2022-03-09T19:45:23.613Z"}` so seems pretty obvious now that I know that but I only just started using both. Sorry I was not trying to be negative, just bad at english and understanding, thank you for your input, I'll try not be negative in the future.

Answer (score 0):

`emailVerified` is a `datetime` object,

so had to change `emailVerified: Any` to `emailVerified: datetime`